# fsolve cannot find a solution even when given one

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I reproduced the issue that I am experiencing with this simple code.

to validate that fsolve is working with the functions below I pre-calculated the functions values with the t values below, so that I am sure that t1 to t4 are a solution.

but even when giving the solution points fsolve is returning always the same solution
[  1.50000000e+02   7.00000000e-01   2.00000000e+02   1.00000000e-01]

What I am doing wrong?
Is there a way to set constraints on the solution, for example all the t variables are between 0 and 1000?

```
t1 = 150.0
t2 = 0.7
t3 = 200.00 
t4 = 0.1 

def FS(z):
    x1=z[0]
    x2=z[1]
    x3=z[2]
    x4=z[3]

    f = np.zeros(4)
    f[0] = x1*x2 + x3*x4 - 125.0
    f[1] = (x1**2/500)*x2 + (x3**2/500)*x4 - 39.5
    f[2] = (x1**3/500**2)*x2 + (x3**3/500**2)*x4 - 12.649999999999999
    f[3] = (x1**4/500**3)*x2 + (x3**4/500**3)*x4 - 4.115
    return f

res = fsolve(FS, [t1, t2, t3, t3])
print(res)
```

[  1.50000000e+02   7.00000000e-01   2.00000000e+02   1.00000000e-01]

Comment: The values in `FS(res)` all have magnitude less than 1e-12.  So `[t1, t2, t3, t4]` is an approximate solution.  What is the problem?

Comment: OK thanks. I tried to simplify my longer code with this sample to make the question shorter, but this redacted sample actually works as expected as you pointed out, it means I have a bug somewhere else, the fsolve usage is actually fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't see your problem. The algorithm converges as expected on (one of the) solutions. This even happens, when you deviate from the solution a lot in your starting values, eg

```
t1 = 10
t2 = 10
t3 = 190
t4 = 10
```

Which gives rise to the solution `[150, 0.7, 200, 0.1]`. But part of the problem is probably that you have more than one solution. Try for instance

```
 t1 = 190
 t2 = 10
 t3 = 10
 t4 = 10
```

If `[t1, t2, t3, t4]` is a solution, then `[t3, t4, t1, t2]` is a solution as well. Which probably makes the algorithm non-convergent for certain starting values like `[1, 1, 1, 1]`. [See some discussion about the underlying algorithm for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46432390/8881141)

Comment: you are correct in this case the solution is correct (I had other cases where the solution was incorrect but I also got a warning), I tried to simplify the code to ask a short question. Anyhow no matter what inputs I put in fsolve I always get the same result. Can I add constraints to the solution?

Comment: Err, no. As I have shown in the answer above, you get different solutions for different starting values. And for certain values, the algorithm is non-convergent. What do you mean by "always get the same result"? The solution to the equation system? Afaik scipy's `fsolve` doesn't provide the possibility to define constraints like "200 > x1 > 100".

Comment: OK thanks. I tried to simplify my longer code with this sample to make the question shorter, but this redacted sample actually works as expected as you pointed out, it means I have a bug somewhere else, the fsolve usage is actually fine. Thank you.